# Want to access input element inside ng-select in angular 6 for getting it's value

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

I'm working on a project where, I want to create a custom feature in ng-select, so that while entering the text in ng-select, it appends it to the binding item and add it as multiselect.

http://embed.plnkr.co/GLuyC0jpIdiEXB6R4FIa/preview

This is the exact implementation needed in angular 6

I'm using angular v6.0

Is there any other method for that implementation in angular 5, as shown in that mentioned **plunker** ??

Sorry, If there was some mistake in question.
As I'm new in Angular.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! You said you are using Angular 6, but your Plunker seems to be using AngularJS 1.4

Comment: @OliverNi

this plunker is the exact Implementation I need on my angular 6 application.

Comment: Oh I see. I'll take a look

Comment: Are you looking for https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/filter?

Comment: Yeah, thanks in advance. 
Actually, I want to create a function, on every (keyup), it appends the data being written inside input element in ng-select, into a empty array of string, which can show that data and can be used as multiselect in ng-select. just as implemented in that demo plunker..

Comment: yeah, but that search would be from the data entered in that input element of ng-select.

Comment: Take a look at this issue - https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select/issues/348

Comment: This is done using ng2-select, but I'm  using ng-select library for my project. 
But i'll try this implementation in this library too.
anyway thanks.

Comment: @OliverNi 

Thanks a lot. I got this exact implementation using [addTag]="true" in ng-select

not needed any function or extra implementation.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found was access to `ng-select` children.

my html:

```
<ng-select [items]="places"
           bindLabel="name"
           [(ngModel)]="selected" dropdownPosition="bottom" #ngselect>
    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-index="index">
        <b>{{item}}</b>
    </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

`ngselect` - NgSelectComponent

`this.myselect.element` - take HTMLElement, and in children we are looking for our `<input>`

```
@ViewChild('myngselect') myselect;

myMethod() {
     const input = this.myselect.element.children[0].children[0].children[1].children[0];
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some explanations for your code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this functionality by using addTag of ng-select,

here is the implementation : 
https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/tags

Answer (score 0):

In your html you have to set name for your input and for ng-select control set id eg. **#myNgSelect**

```html
  <ng-select #myNgSelect
           [items]="places"
           [(ngModel)]="selected"
           [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
           [searchable]="false"
           bindValue="id"
           bindLabel="name"
           (open)="onOpenMyNgSelect()"
           dropdownPosition="bottom">
    <ng-template ng-header-tmp>
      <input type="text" name="myNgSelectInput"/>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-select>
```

In code you have to do like below and you should access to your custom input control in ng-select

```js
 @ViewChild('myNgSelect') myNgSelect: NgSelectComponent;

 onOpenMyNgSelect() {
    setTimeout(() => { //we are waiting for open ng-select control and generate our custom input
      const elements = document.getElementsByName('myNgSelectInput')
      
      if (!isNullOrUndefined(elements) && elements.lenght > 0) {
          const inputElement = elements[0] as HTMLInputElement;

          if (!isNullOrUndefined(inputElement)) {
            // do something here
          }
      }
    }, 800);
  }
```